# React,Typescript, ".map is not a function" error in recursive map when using cloneElement to pass a method on component props.children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a react newbie, and trying to write a **CustomFormComp** that will be used like below,
I will have some form element components too, which will be used like **InputComponent**.
The child Components (**InputComponent**) need to get a method from the parent component(**CustomFormComp**) to handle **onChnage** and lift up their state to **CustomFormComp**,
although they should be able to combine **onChange** with a given method to them as callbacks.
And also if inner components bind correctly I should be able to pass them some data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CustomFormComp from "../Form";
import InputComponent from "../FormElements/InputComponent";

interface IState { }

interface IProps { }

interface FormElData {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export class CustomForm extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  render() {
    const formData: FormElData = {
      email: "someone@some-mail.com",
      phone: "sdfsdf",
      address: "asdhf akshdfkahsdkahsdflka hsfnasdk f"
    };

    return (
      <CustomFormComp FormData={formData}>
        <h2>f</h2>
        asd
        <h3>asdf</h3>
        <div className="c1">
          <div className="c2">
            <div className="c3">
              <InputComponent label="email: " name="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="c33"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="c22"></div>
        </div>
        <InputComponent label="phone: " name="phone" />
      </CustomFormComp>
    );
  }
}
```

So far this is my **customFromComp**:

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode, Fragment } from "react"

interface FormElData {
    [key: string]: string
}

interface IState {
    FormData: {
        [key: string]: string
    }
}

type ICustomFormChildren = Array<null | React.ReactChild> //  | React.ReactChildren

interface IProps {
    FormData: FormElData
    children: ICustomFormChildren
}

class CustomFormComp extends Component<IProps, IState> {
    state = {
        FormData: {}
    }

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props)
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.state.FormData = this.props.FormData
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            FormData: this.props.FormData
        })
    }

    handleInputChange(inputData: FormElData) {
        const newFormData: any = { ...this.state.FormData }
        newFormData[inputData.name] = inputData.value

        this.setState({
            FormData: newFormData
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    recursiveClone(children: ICustomFormChildren): ICustomFormChildren {
        return (children).map((child, index: number) => {
            let value: string

            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                if (
                    child.props &&
                    this.state.FormData &&
                    (this.state.FormData as any)[child.props.name]) {
                    value = (this.state.FormData as any)[child.props.name]

                    return React.cloneElement(child, {
                        onChange: this.handleInputChange.bind(this),
                        key: index,
                        value: value
                    })
                } else if (!child.props || !Object.keys(child.props).length) {
                    return <Fragment key={index}>{child}</Fragment>
                } else {
                    console.log(Array.isArray(child.props.children), child.props.children)
                    return React.cloneElement(
                        child,
                        { key: index },
                        this.recursiveClone(child.props.children)
                    )
                }
            } else {
                return <Fragment key={index}>{child}</Fragment>
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const newChildren = this.recursiveClone(this.props.children)

        return (
            <form style={{ direction: "ltr" }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {newChildren}
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomFormComp
```

and this is my **InputComponent**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

interface inputData {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  value?: string,
  onChange?(e:any): void
}

class InputComponent extends React.Component<inputData> {
  constructor(props:inputData) {
    super(props)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e:any) {
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange({
      name: this.props.name,
      value: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const value:string | undefined = this.props.value
    const name:string = this.props.name

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <label>
          {this.props.label}
          <input name={name} value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    )
  }
}

export default InputComponent
```

Now I think It should work but some types error prevent page from loading, this is the error:
[image]

```
**UPDATE**
```

Main problem here is this:
The first time that i run the map it works fine, when I pass the *child.props.children* to in recursion it does not recognize the new argument(children which is child.props.children) and it trow an error.

Comment: This is the kind of error you get when "children" is not an array, so it could be undefined or null. Try adding an undefined/null check before to see if the error changes.

Comment: Try something like 
if(children && children.length > 0) return children.map ...
else return []

Comment: if you can make the example code available on https://codesandbox.io/ it could be easier to debug the problem.

Comment: I think maybe you have copied the wrong code for the input component because its just the same as the customform code

Comment: sorry fixed it!

Comment: please don't delete your post, just edit. good luck. ♥️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that children in react are not always an array, if you have only one child it is not an array.

Your code will work if you force recursive clone to send an array when there is only one child. See here:

```
recursiveClone(children: ICustomFormChildren): ICustomFormChildren {
    return children.map((child, index: number) => {
      let value: string;

      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        if (
          child.props &&
          this.state.FormData &&
          (this.state.FormData as any)[child.props.name]
        ) {
          value = (this.state.FormData as any)[child.props.name];

          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            onChange: this.handleInputChange.bind(this),
            key: index,
            value: value
          });
        } else if (!child.props || !Object.keys(child.props).length) {
          return <Fragment key={index}>{child}</Fragment>;
        } else {
          console.log(
            Array.isArray(child.props.children),
            child.props.children
          );
          if (!Array.isArray(child.props.children)) {
            return React.cloneElement(
              child,
              { key: index },
              this.recursiveClone([child.props.children])
            );
          }
          return React.cloneElement(
            child,
            { key: index },
            this.recursiveClone(child.props.children)
          );
        }
      } else {
        return <Fragment key={index}>{child}</Fragment>;
      }
    });
  }
```

I added this if in your else

```
if (!Array.isArray(child.props.children)) {
            return React.cloneElement(
              child,
              { key: index },
              this.recursiveClone([child.props.children])
            );
          }
```

I tested it here in this https://codesandbox.io/s/new-surf-d17rk

Comment: Glad I can help :)